# Does plutonium need to be squeezed to produce an uncontrolled chain reaction?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, explosions

I guess what I am asking is if in theory you could start with a certain amount of plutonium would it explode with out being squeezed together as is done in an atomic bomb ?

Normally what happens ( and this is an assumption on my part , I am not an atomic bomb scientist )  two or more sections of the isotope in question are rammed together in a very controlled implosion caused by chemical explosives.

But what would happen if the isotope was just manufactured as one large chunk of material?  Would it spontaneously detonate or would you still have to squeeze it?

Comment: Well, if it would explode how would you make it in the first place?

Comment: Pu-240 contamination is inevitable in practice,  the high rate of spontaneous fission of Pu-240 will make the bomb fizzle instead of exploding.  An implosion device gets around this problem by reducing the critical mass for the chain reaction.

Comment: I see your points....i did find an article that explains this in detail so I am ok now

Comment: If you found an answer please close the question (or provide a summary of the answer yourself an accept it).

Comment: The answer is posted below and I have already accepted it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "trick" to a nuclear chain reaction is that each fission triggers more than one other fission event. That requires the emitted neutrons to hit enough other atoms to have a chance of causing fission. But in an ordinary block of plutonium the density of atoms is not enormous, and there are edges where neutrons get lost to the environment. A sufficiently big block would presumably produce a nuclear "fizzle" as chain reactions would release some of the energy (enough to destroy it) but not enough to actually explode.

The solution in a fission bomb is both to compress the material, but also to surround it with a neutron reflector. This makes each fission event likely to trigger several more events producing a boom rather than a fizzle.

Alex Wellerstein has a [great writeup about why "critical mass" is the wrong concept](http://blog.nuclearsecrecy.com/2015/04/10/critical-mass/) (it should be "critical condition") and [a very fun interactive visualisation of the process](http://blog.nuclearsecrecy.com/misc/criticality/). Notice how piling up a lot of extra atoms makes the chain reaction longer but still relatively inefficient and dirty, while compressing inside a neutron reflector gets most of the energy out of the atoms. Just having a reflector does little on its own here.

Comment: I have been look for a "nice" introductory explanation and your is the most intuitive . Ok :-)